# Mod_rewrite not combining a dynamic subdirectory rewrite and a static one

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got the following .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ user.php?username=$1 [QSA]
    RewriteRule ^tag/(.*)$ tag.php?tag=$1
</IfModule>
```

I need to cover the following use cases:

1. http://example.com/**foo** -> http://example.com/user.php?username=**foo**
2. http://example.com/**about** -> http://example.com/**about/index.php**
3. http://example.com/**tag/bar** -> http://example.com/tag.php?tag=**bar**

The current mod_rewrite rules cover cases 1 and 2 (about/index.php is a real location). I'm having trouble getting them to cover case 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it like this by reordering your rules and turning `MultiViews` option off. Also skip files & directories from all your rewrite rules:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^tag/(.+)$ tag.php?tag=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ user.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Oh, you're a lifesaver, that fixed it - and thank you for tidying up my whole file. Could you explain what turning off `MultiViews` does in this instance, if you have the time?

Comment: Option `MultiViews` (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html) is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So if `/file` is the URL then Apache will serve `/file.html`.